# Solana JavaScript Interaction

Tags: javascript

**Is there any way to interact to solana smart contracts using javascript?**
I have tried many APIs pf moralis and quicknode but I need sole interaction between the smart contract and js.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many libraries that can be used to interact Javascript with smart contracts.

The prominent libraries are Solana/web3js: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/

Also @project-serum/anchor : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@project-serum/anchor?activeTab=versions

You can make rpc calls using @project-serum/anchor to smart contracts

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use a typescript or javascript client to interact with on chain programs
Here is one demo https://github.com/Nagaprasadvr/SolQuotes